# PostgreSQL: Select particular column and its total row count

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I will explain my problem with an sample example

```
create table foo(id int,idx int,idy int,fld int,fldx varchar);

insert into foo values (1,2,3,55,'AA'),(2,3,4,77,'AB'),(3,4,8,55,'AX'),(9,10,15,77,'AR'),
                       (3,4,8,11,'AX'),(3,4,8,65,'AX'),(3,4,8,77,'AX');




   id,idx,idy, fld,fldx
    1 2   3    55  AA
    2 3   4    77  AB
    3 4   8    55  AX
    9 10  15   77  AR
    3 4   8    11  AX
    3 4   8    65  AX
    3 4   8    77  AX
```

I need to select only column `fld` and its total count of each column(`fld`) in descending order

Expected Result :

```
fld count
---------
77  3
55  2
11  1
65  1
```

Comment: check out `count()` and `group by` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select fld
      ,count(fld) rw_count 
from foo 
group by fld 
order by rw_count desc
```

[**Group By**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

Comment: Why you need subquery ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select fld,count(*) from foo group by 1 order by 2 desc ;
```